# Returning the correct xml structure from query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I'm trying to select data from a consumer parent table and inner join on multiple child tables and return it as XML.

I have the Consumer parent table and 2 child tables ConsumerPhone and Consumer Address.

The Output I want should look like this

```
<Consumer Username="eallen">
  <ConsumerPhone/>
  <ConsumerAddress />
</Consumer>
<Consumer Username="jgibson">
  <ConsumerPhone/>
  <ConsumerAddress />
</Consumer>
```

But my query (which I think is the issue) is placing the Consumer Address inside the ConsumerPhone element

```
<Consumer Username="eallen">
  <ConsumerPhone>
    <ConsumerAddress />
  </ConsumerPhone>
</Consumer>
<Consumer Username="jgibson">
  <ConsumerPhone>
    <ConsumerAddress />
  </ConsumerPhone>
</Consumer>
```

Here is the query

```
SELECT Consumer.Username,ConsumerPhone.Number,ConsumerAddress.Country
  FROM [dbo].[Consumer] Consumer
  LEFT JOIN  [dbo].[ConsumerPhone] ConsumerPhone
  ON Consumer.ConsumerID = ConsumerPhone.ConsumerID

  LEFT JOIN  [dbo].[ConsumerAddress] ConsumerAddress
  ON Consumer.ConsumerID = ConsumerAddress.ConsumerID
   order by Consumer.ConsumerID asc
  OFFSET 100 ROWS
 FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
 FOR XML AUTO;
```

I'm not sure how to fix my query to get the output I'm looking for.

Thanks

I changed it to use nested FOR XML Statements to allow for multiple values in the correct element.

```
    SELECT
   Consumer.*,
   (SELECT
       cp.*
        FROM dbo.ConsumerPhone cp
        WHERE cp.ConsumerID = Consumer.ConsumerID
        FOR XML PATH('ConsumerPhone'), TYPE
       ) AS 'ConsumerPhoneNos'
    FROM dbo.Consumer Consumer
    where Consumer.ConsumerID = 220901
FOR XML PATH('Consumer'), ROOT('Consumers')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
     SELECT Consumer.Username AS "@Username",
            ConsumerPhone.Number AS "ConsumerPhone",
            ConsumerAddress.Country AS "ConsumerAddress"
     FROM [dbo].[Consumer] Consumer
     LEFT JOIN  [dbo].[ConsumerPhone] ConsumerPhone
     ON Consumer.ConsumerID = ConsumerPhone.ConsumerID

     LEFT JOIN  [dbo].[ConsumerAddress] ConsumerAddress
     ON Consumer.ConsumerID = ConsumerAddress.ConsumerID
     order by Consumer.ConsumerID asc
     OFFSET 100 ROWS
     FETCH NEXT 100 ROWS ONLY
     FOR XML PATH ('Consumer');
```